# IE Vertical Text Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rotation

I currently have a feedback tab thats fixed to the right side of the browser and rotated 90 degrees. The tab looks fine in firefox and chrome but in IE the box rotates but not the text. Its a really simple button and will probably have a really simple solution I'm just missing.

```
    #feedback{
  color:#FFF;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:200px; right:-56px;
  width:140px; 
  height:35px; 
  line-height:40px;
  background:#727948;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:18px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
          box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  opacity:0.8;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);/* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* ie9 */
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2); /* ie8 */
  writing-mode:tb-rl; /* ie8 */ 
}

#feedback:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nhf5m4y1/

Answer (score 3):

`writing-mode:tb-rl` is deprecated, you should use `writing-mode:vertical-rl` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, removing the write-mode fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following css: `writing-mode: tb-rl;`. It is redundant and deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

For IE have `-ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;`